# How to add text to editext

Tags: android, button, textview, android-edittext

I've got a problem with populating an edittext. Using the following code i can set the text just fine, however what i am trying to do is add to the edittext. For example the following code displays a "1" in my edittext but if I press it again it just replaces the "1" with "1" and so on. What i need is it to display "1111" if I press it four times.

heres my code:

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
                    case R.id.button1:

                        Button txtnum = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

                        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                        bundle.putString("number1", txtnum.getText().toString());
                        String title = bundle.getString("number1");
                        ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1)).setText(title);



                        break;
```

Hope this makes sence. (I'm a noob)
If anyone can help me with this I'd really appreciate it.
thanks Steve

Answer (score 25, accepted):

try this code

```
String title = bundle.getString("number1");
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
editText.append(title);
```

if you want to set the only new value use this

```
editText.setText(title);
```

Answer (score 2):

You'd need `editText.setText(editText.getText() + "string");`.

```
EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
et.setText(et.getText() + title);
```

Answer (score 1):

Should be as simple as:

```
editText.setText("hello");
```

In your code:

```
EditText editText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.x);
editText.setText("hello");
```

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't answer his question. He wants to append to the already existing text.

Answer (score 1):

```
String title = bundle.getString("number1");
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
editText.setText(editText.getText().toString() + title);
```

Comment: thank you it worked.. you guys are fast!! so lets say i wanted to delete one at a time if for instance the user pressed it too many time do you know how i would go about that?

Comment: Just get the current contents of the text edit: editText.getText().toString(), change the string in any way you want (e.g. by removing the last character), and use the resulting string in your editText: editText.setText(myNewString);

Answer (score 0):

Set edit text to the previuos value plus the new value.

```
EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
et.setText(et.GetText() + title);
```

Comment: `(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1)` Extra brackets aren't needed.

Comment: Yeah I copied the code from the question and didn't examine it. Developer's sin.

Comment: setText() is not the right method to add new contents. You should use append()